# Is it possible to add Quality gate name as Seach Createria in Sonar Qube?

Tags: sonarqube

I have some projects scanned by sonar that belongs to a specific Group of projects. All of them have been assigned to the same Quality Gate.

So it would be great to filter them by QualityGate Name. Is this somehow possible?

Thanks,
Daniel

Answer (score 0):

1 - On Quality Gates administration page you can have the full list of projects using a QG

2 - with API REST xxxxxx/api/qualitygates/search

look at https://next.sonarqube.com/sonarqube/web_api/api/qualitygates/search you have sample